# pirates treasure divide problem

Tags: number-theory

A group of 12 pirates agree to divide a treasure chest of gold coins among themselves as follows. The $k^{th}$ pirate to take a share takes $\frac{k}{12}$ of the coins that remain in the chest. The number of coins initially in the chest is the smallest number for which this arrangement will allow each pirate to receive a positive whole number of coins. How many coins does the $12^{th}$ pirate receive?

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a 'do my homework for free' service! You could by the least indicate a restriction on the initial number of coins in the chest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get below table for each pirate if assume total number as 1:

\begin{array} {|l|l|l|}
\hline N & Taken & Remaining \\ \hline
1 & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{11}{12} \\
\hline
2 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{2}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12} \\
\hline
3 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12} \\
\hline
4 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12} \\
\hline
5 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12} \\
\hline
6 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12} \\
\hline
7 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12} \\
\hline
8 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12} \\
\hline
9 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{12} \\
\hline
10 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{2}{12} \\
\hline
11 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{2}{12}\cdot \frac{11}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{2}{12}\cdot \frac{1}{12} \\
\hline
12 & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{2}{12}\cdot \frac{1}{12}\cdot \frac{12}{12} & \frac{11}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{2}{12}\cdot \frac{1}{12}\cdot \frac{0}{12} \\
\hline
\end{array}

So the $12^{th}$ will take $\frac{12!}{12^{12}}$,which is $\frac{1925}{35831808}$. So the smallest number should be 1925.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the chest has $A$ coins, after the $k$'th pirate passes the chest has $\frac{(12-k)A}{12}$ coins.

So if the chest initially has $A$ coins, after the first $11$ pirates pass it will have $\frac{11!A}{12^{12}}$, this number must be an integer. Therefore $12^{12}$ must divide $A\times(12^{12},11!)=A\times 2^83^4$, so $A$ is at least $\frac{12^{12}}{2^84^3}$, and clearly it works.